# Are there a formula for generalize nested summation?

Tags: summation

I have played a game that have a mechanic of summation and want to write algorithm to calculate it

It is a game that let you grow an insect nest. It has `Ant` that give you 1 food per sec. `Queen` give you 1 `Ant` per sec. `Nest` give you 1 `Queen` per sec

And so for simplicity I would make it start with 1 nest the formula would be

$$\sum_{i=0}^s 1 = s\\\text{for Queen I would get from 1 nest}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^s i = \frac{s^2 + s}{2}\\\text{for Ant I would get from queens hatched from 1 nest}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^s \frac{i^2 + i}{2} = \frac{1}{2} (\sum_{i=0}^s i^2 + \sum_{i=0}^s i) = \frac{s^3 + 3s^2 + 2s}{6}\\\text{for Food I would get from ants hatched so far}$$

It seem like there should be able to write formula or algorithm for any depth. Are there any formula like that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we can define
$s_0(n) = 1,
s_{m+1}(n)
=\sum_{i=1}^n s_m(i)
$.

You have calculated
$s_1(n) = n,
s_2(n)= \dfrac{n^2+n}{2},
s_3(n) = \dfrac{n^3+3n^2+2n}{6}
$.

Note that
$s_2(n)= \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}
$
and
$s_3(n) 
= \dfrac{n(n^2+3n+2)}{6}
= \dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}
$.

Do you see the pattern here?

Hint:

$s_4(n) 
= \dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{24}
$.

Make a conjecture
and try to prove it,
by induction of course.

Comment: Oh man why it seem (n + p)!/p!n! come out here...

Comment: Do you have any source of mathematician who come up with this first?

Comment: Euler at the latest, possibly Fermat or that era.

Comment: Thanks. Does this formula has a name?

Answer (score 2):

Faulhaber's formula might be relevant, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula